# What happened with this question?

Tags: support, specific-question

What happened to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3326056)?

I got a badge for it and upvotes for the answer on it.  Where did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326009/what-resolution-should-i-make-my-image-backgrounds-for-my-universal-ios-app-so-th/3326056#3326056) (10k+ only).

The person who asked the question, deleted it 6 hours ago.  Your answer was, unfortunately, deleted with it.

Comment: It's undeleted now